# Why is the array not showing up in the table view?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, deque

I am appending data from parse into an array, but when I try to load array in table view nothing shows up. The array is populated, but nothing is showing up. How do I fix this?

```
class View2: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

  var ret = [String]()

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return ret.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

    cell.textLabel?.text = ret[indexPath.row]

    return cell
   }
}
```

Comment: Where you've this line `var ret = [String]()`? What your ret have? Can you show us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After set 'ret' value, you have to reload table.

In my case,

```
var ret = [String](){
    didSet{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case I forgot to connect the UITableView datasource outlet to the ViewController.

[image: storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your tableview is being reloaded after you receive the data. Use `tableViewName.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to `reloadData()` method of `UITableView` in the setter of your array.