# pushing data to UITableView is not showing

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tableview

I am trying to push data from UIViewController to a UITableView.  Now I am able to push one piece of data to the cell and it appears fine.  The problem I am having if I go back and to push more data it just overrides the cell.  Rather than going on to another cell.  I have tried the suggestion from the this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537391/why-is-the-array-not-showing-up-in-the-table-view)
and `self.tableView.reloadData()`. This does not seem to have solved the issue I have.  Below is the code that I have written.

```
class PredictorTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var predictorTrack = ""
    var firstDriver = ""
    var secondDriver = ""
    var thirdDriver = ""

    var grandPrix = [GrandPrix]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.grandPrix.append(GrandPrix(granPrix: predictorTrack, firstDriver: firstDriver, secondDriver: secondDriver, thirdDriver: thirdDriver))
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.navigationItem.title = "Predictor"
        let backbutton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        backbutton.setTitle(" Back", for: .normal)
        backbutton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        backbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.backbuttonpressed), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backbutton)
        setupNavBar()

    }

    @objc func backbuttonpressed() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func setupNavBar(){
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return grandPrix.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! GrandPrixTableViewCell
        let race = self.grandPrix[indexPath.row]
        // Configure the cell...
        cell.grandPrix.text = race.grandPrix
        cell.firstPostion.text = race.firstDriver
        cell.secondPosition.text = race.secondDriver
        cell.thirdPostion.text = race.thirdDriver

        return cell
    }
```

Below is the function to prepare for segue.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "getPredictor" {
        let predictorVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let vc = predictorVC.topViewController as! PredictorTableViewController
        vc.predictorTrack = TrackTextField.text!
        vc.firstDriver = firstTextField.text!
        vc.secondDriver = secondTextField.text!
        vc.thirdDriver = thirdTextField.text!
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to set **didSet** to your **grandPrix** variable which was mentioned at your stackoverflow question link? try this ***var grandPrix = [GrandPrix]() { didSet {self.tableView.reloadData()} }***. You said you go back, where you go back? did you dismiss the ViewController? then probably your data model has only one element. need some more clarification about **GrandPrix** and how you populate [GrandPrix]() array.

Comment: I've tried that Imrul and it still overrides the cell.  So only showing one piece of data.

Comment: did you check when you go back and return, how much elements [GrandPrix]() array has?

Comment: it is just showing the following ```[Racing_Weather.GrandPrix]
[Racing_Weather.GrandPrix]
[Racing_Weather.GrandPrix]```

Comment: maybe your array does not storing previous data, when you dismiss the VC, your array becomes empty. when you dismiss the PredictorTableViewController, in debug section use **po** command to see if the ***var grandPrix*** is empty or not.

Comment: Performing a segue (other than an unwind segue) creates a new instance of the view controller and displays that new instance. It won't have any of the values that were unique to the other instance.

Comment: back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that whenever your go back to previous `UIViewConntroller` instance of `PredictorTableViewController` gets deleted from the memory, so all of the data that is associated with it is also gone (`grandPrix` array).

I can suggest you 3 solutions:

---

**FIRST**

Keep your `grandPrix` array in parent `UIViewController` and pass it in to `PredictorTableViewController` when segue is performed like so:

```
var grandPrix = [GrandPrix]()

...

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "getPredictor" {
        let predictorVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let vc = predictorVC.topViewController as! PredictorTableViewController

        // append new GrandPrix to local array
        self.grandPrix.append(GrandPrix(granPrix: TrackTextField.text!, firstDriver: firstTextField.text!, secondDriver: secondTextField.text!, thirdDriver: thirdTextField.text!)) 

        // important part: pass local data to destination
        vc.grandPrix = self.grandPrix    
    }
}
```

---

**SECOND**

Keep `PredictorTableViewController` as a strong reference in parent `UIViewCointroller` and manually push `PredictorTableViewController` to `UINavigationController` when you need it.

```
// Strong lazy reference
lazy var predicatorController: PredicatorTableViewController = {

    // If needed, this can be loaded from a NIB or Storyboard
    return PredicatorTableViewController()
}()
```

To use this call following `UINavigationController` function:

```
// generate new data for predicatorController and append it to grandPrix array
predicatorController.grandPrix.append(...)

// show predicatorController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(predicatorController, animated: true)
```

P.S. with this solutions DO NOT use segues.

---

**THIRD**

Same idea as first suggestion, but data of `grandPrix` array will be stored in local cache (CoreData database for example). You will have to write local cache data retrieval/storing functions and use it accordingly when you need to access existing and store new GrandPrix objects into your local cache.

---

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you, Tomas, for that helped a lot.